# MySQL max_user_connections vs max_connections

Tags: php, mysql

SADLY i could not find any straight-forward explanation to this query anywhere, not even in MySQL documentations.

Some people in various forums said max_user_connections can never be greater than max_connections? For example: if one user has `3 max_user_connections` and another user has `15 max_user_connections`, then they say the max_connections must be at least above `3+15 = 18`.

However, mysql doc says, max allowed value of [max_user_connections is 4294967295](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections) which is MUCH LARGER THAN the max allowed value of [max_connections is 100000](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections).

Can somebody please explain how do these two options in MySQL impact one another.

Comment: ignore the limits, they don't tell you anything about usage, they are not used to explain the difference

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly answered in the manual

Comment: the specific query here is the connection and relation between the max_user_connections and max_connections... there is no resource which makes a direct note of the relation between the two.... that clarification is necessary.... hence i asked this question... please don't close it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[max_user_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html)

> One means of restricting client use of MySQL server resources is to
>   set the global `max_user_connections` system variable to a nonzero
>   value. This limits the number of simultaneous connections that can be
>   made by any given account, but places no limits on what a client can
>   do once connected. In addition, setting max_user_connections does not
>   enable management of individual accounts. Both types of control are of
>   interest to MySQL administrators.

[max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)

> The maximum permitted number of simultaneous client connections. By
>   default, this is 151

---

comment by [dagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557846/dagon) :

> `max_connections` = the total connection limit
>   `max_user_connections` = the per user limit

---

Hence, the value of `max_user_connections` must never exceed the value of `max_connections`.

Comment: in summery: **max_connections** = the total connection limit, **max_user_connections** = the per user limit

Comment: so that affirms my query that max_user_connections cannot exceed max_connections... right?

Comment: thanks for the feedback... can you please edit your answer to include that specific clarification... i have seen too many people asking for this clarification in too many places but nowhere is there any direct connection or remark made like this

Answer (score 0):

Although both defines an upper limit on number of simultaneous connections, [max_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) has a global scope only (it's connection limit of the server) whereas [max_user_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections) has global as well as session [scope](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-system-variables.html) (its's the connection limit per user).

As mentioned, max value of max_connections is apparently smaller (than max_user_connections), however if it's default value is increased beyond a certain level, you may run up against a [limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-cache.html) imposed by the operating system on per-process number of open file descriptors. Comparing max values will mislead.