# What's the use of max_connections column in mysql.user table?

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-error-1064, mysql-5.7

We all know that:

**max_connections** refers to the total number of connections that all clients can create on mysql instance simultaneously.

And **max_user_connections** refers to the total number of connections that user can create simultaneously.

So why there is separate column named max_connections for all users in mysql.user table?  Because **max_connections** is the same for all users and is a global variable for all the connections?

Comment: I have found some below information from 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020330/mysql-max-user-connections-vs-max-connections

max_connections = the total connection limit, 
max_user_connections = the per user limit
max_user_connections cannot exceed max_connections

Comment: @AnkitDoshi this i already wrote in my question.
max_connection is total connection limit so why in all user rows, its a global thing, right ?

Comment: Yeah its a global thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html):

> MySQL permits limits for individual accounts on use of these server resources:
>
> - The number of queries an account can issue per hour
> - The number of updates an account can issue per hour
> - The number of times an account can connect to the server per hour
> - The number of simultaneous connections to the server by an account
>
> ...
> The server stores resource limits for an account in the user table row corresponding to the account. The `max_questions`, `max_updates`, and `max_connections` columns store the per-hour limits, and the `max_user_connections` column stores the `MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS` limit.

Comment: yes this is correct, it stores the per hour limit..
thanks